# Responsive 3-column grid layout leaves open spaces

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, percentage

I am building a responsive portfolio website with a grid of thumbnails. It goes from a one-column grid up to a three-column grid depending on the browser width.

The problem occurs only in the three-column grid. When I resize the browser, sometimes the grid just skips two thumbnails and leaves an empty space. The thumbnails are pushed further in the grid like this:

[image: error drawing]

Now, this only happens sometimes. When I'm resizing the browser I can see it switching from the normal grid to the error grid and back (at least in Chrome and Safari, Firefox always displays the error when resizing).

Here is my html/css for the thumbnail divs.

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnails">
    <div>*image*</div>
    <div>*image*</div>
    <div>*image*</div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.thumbnails div{
    width: 33.33333%;
}
```

All of my elements have box-sizing: border-box; on them. I hope I didn't leave out any other relevant info. I haven't encountered this particular problem before. Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a good case to use flexbox. [Example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/amwill/jowr0jds/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For as far as i know this could fix it

```
.thumbnails div:nth-child(3n + 4){
   clear: left;
}
```

If one of the div's in a row does not have the same height as the others you need `clear: left;` on the first one of the next row.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work :) Is there a reason why it acts all weird without adding that particular line of code? I can't really see why this error would occur in the first place.

Comment: It starts acting weird becouse the height of the divs isnt the same, if the height of all the divs was the same you wouldnt run into this problem