# 3 column grid layout leaves empty gaps

Tags: html, css

I have a website which uses a 3 column layout for the products page. However since yesterday somehow the layout changed and now I am left with gaps between the columns like this:

[image: The problem]

I found this post which describes the same problem as I have: [Responsive 3-column grid layout leaves open spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058493/responsive-3-column-grid-layout-leaves-open-spaces) but using the recommended fix to use "clear: left;" on every first column of a row doesn't work for me, as it then changes to a 2 column layout which I don't want.

Comment: How we can help you without seeing your code? Post your relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your blocks same height? try using this on parent element:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

Can you show full code?
are they all wrapped around one single element?

Comment: Somehow some blocks weren't the same height. By using your provided css on the parent element fixed it. Thanks man.